# Errors in numerical integration plot

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

```
xa[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2)/W^2]*
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2], {x, 0, 
   r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]
xb[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2)/W^2]*
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2], {x, -r, 
   0}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]

xf[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, W_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  e1^2*Exp[-(2*((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2))/W^2], {x, 0, 
   r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]
xg[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, W_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  e1^2*Exp[-(2*((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2))/W^2], {x, -r, 
   0}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]

x1[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 xa[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r] + 
  xf[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, W, r]
x2[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 xb[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r] + 
  xg[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, W, r]
x3[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 x1[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r] - 
  x2[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r]
x4[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 x1[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r] + 
  x2[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r]
x5[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_] := 
 x3[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r]/
  x4[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r]


  With[{\[Delta]x = 0.00005, \[Delta]y = 0, e1 = 3, e2 = 100, 
  W = 0.00015, r = 0.005}, 
 Plot[Abs[x5[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r]], {L, 0, 0.00015}]]
```

I wish to understand the dependence of x5 on W,L and [Delta]x. 
However, when I try plotting x5 as a function of L, I get some error messages and the resulting graph has a strange behaviour close to zero (It is flat for a while, and then suddenly dips down). What is wrong here?

Comment: If, as the warning message suggests, you include the option `MinRecursion->4` to each of your `NIntegrate` then you see that the function is not flat and suddenly turns down, but instead smoothly decreases starting at x==0.

Comment: Thank you! But I still have a problem. Although the resulting graph is smooth, I still get an error message "Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option"  How do I know if this plot is indeed correct?

Comment: And I just increased MinRecursion to 10, MaxRecursion to 20, and AccuracyGoal to 10. But the graph got worse close to zero. I don't understand why this happened.

Comment: Plot is probably "probing" your integrands with a few points to see if it can find a way to optimize the calculation. If it gets zero from some of those probes then It gives you the warning. Unfortunately it may be unlikely to see exactly what it is doing inside the `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the options:

```
MinRecursion -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 40
```

to `NIntegrate` in the "x*" functions we get a result only with precision of integrand messages and with a good looking plot. (As discussed in the comments.)

[image]